# Why we haven't discovered different planetary systems yet as described?

Tags: vedas, gods, bhagavad-gita, bhagavata-purana, demi-god

While I was reading more and more, I got to know that there are different lokas below and above earth and the distance described for them is only some yojana sway (1 yojana = 8 miles = 12 kilometers), we have discovered planets hundreds of light years away ( 1 light year = 9.46 × 10^12 km). These planetary systems are around 10000, 25000, 80000 yojanas away then why we haven't found these planets and any person on these planets?

Comment: They're not visible.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but this is the only reason I am asking, why they are not visible?

Comment: They are made up of matter that is too subtle to interact with or detect with our gross senses and instruments. It is similar to dark matter, which doesn't reflect light, so it's invisble.

Comment: I totally agree with you but what about the lower planetary systems which are more gross than us, they should be seen by us

Comment: The Patalas are definitely not more gross than us; they're as subtle as the upper realms. All these supernatural realms are made of up subtle matter.

Comment: Please check out this, https://www.google.com/search?q=are+the+lower+planetary+systems+more+gross+or+subtle&client=tablet-android-samsung-nf-rev1&prmd=nsmiv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiG5vyyrITwAhVcyzgGHTM7DxUQ_AUoBHoECAIQBA&biw=800&bih=1280#imgrc=FI_RHcXKKXUoLM

Comment: If they were more gross than us, we'd obviously see them.

Comment: @Ikshvaku What do "gross" and "subtle" mean in this context? Is there any evidence in the relevant literature for the claim that between any two worlds the "subtle"-er one must be able to observe the "gross"-er one?

Comment: @chhatra Ghosts can see us and interact with us, but we can't see them. And they have subtler bodies, so it appears that way.

Comment: @Ikshvaku I'm tempted to say that it is quite a large extrapolation but I assume you have some particular state of "ghost" in mind? I'm not checking the exact stages, but effectively the dead spend some time bound to this world before the funeral rites are completed during which period they may interact with the living.

Comment: @Ikshvaku yes there is evidence, in our literature that all the above planetary systems are subtle, and all the Lowery planetary systems are gross, https://www.google.com/search?q=subtle+gross+planetary+systems&client=tablet-android-samsung-nf-rev1&prmd=sinv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN_t7OpKXwAhU78HMBHeHsAZ8Q_AUoAnoECAIQAg&biw=800&bih=1280&dpr=1.5#imgrc=FI_RHcXKKXUoLM

Comment: @AnshGoel If they're grosser than thus, then we why can't we see or interact with them?